# Inserting multiple elements at known locations in a vector

Tags: c++, performance, vectors, insertion-sort

**Goal**

In the vector `x`, I would like to insert the elements of the vector `values` at indices stored in vector `positions`. Note that the vector `positions` is not sorted.

For example, from the following input

```
std::vector<char> x = {'H','e','l','l','W','o','l','d'};
std::vector<char> values = {'r','o'};
std::vector<size_t> positions = {6,4};
```

I expect the following output

```
std::vector<char> x = {'H','e','l','l','o','W','o','r','l','d'};
```

**My implementation**

The idea is first to sort `positions` and reorder `values` accordingly. Then, I resize the vector `x` so that it can welcome the new elements. Finally, I iterate through the vector `x` from its last index to the lowest position of insertion by asking at each step what element should go there and move this element (whether it comes from a lower index in `x` of from `values`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

//// Print a vector
template <typename T>
void print(std::vector<T>& x)
{
    for (auto& e : x) std::cout << e << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

//// Return the indices to inform on how to sort the inputted vector
template <typename T>
std::vector<uint32_t> sort_indices(const std::vector<T> &v)
{

  // initialize original index locations
  std::vector<uint32_t> idx(v.size());
  std::iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);

  // sort indexes based on comparing values in v
  std::sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(),
       [&v](uint32_t i1, uint32_t i2) {return v[i1] < v[i2];});

  return idx;
}

//// reorder vector based on indices
template <typename T>
void reorder(std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<uint32_t>& order)  
{   
    auto v2 = v;
    for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; i++)
    {
        v[i] = v2[order[i]];
    }
}


//// Insert multiple elements at specified positions into vector
template<typename T>
void insertAtPositions(std::vector<T>& x, std::vector<T>& values, std::vector<size_t>& positions)
{
  // assert values and positions are the same size
  assert(values.size() == positions.size());

  // Special case - values is empty
  if (values.size() == 0) return;

  // sort the values and the positions where those values should be inserted
  auto indices = sort_indices(positions);
  reorder(positions, indices);
  reorder(values, indices);

  // Special case - x is empty
  if (x.size() == 0)
  {
      x.swap(values);
      return;
  }

  // Allocate memory to x
  x.resize(x.size() + values.size());

  
  // Move things to make room for insertions and insert
  int pos_index = positions.size()-1;
  for (size_t i = x.size()-1 ; pos_index >= 0 ; --i)
  {
    if (i == positions[pos_index] + pos_index)
    {
      // A new value should go at index i
      x[i] = std::move(values[pos_index]);
      --pos_index;
    } else
    {
      // The value from index 'i-pos_index-1' must go to index 'i'
      x[i] = std::move(x[i-pos_index-1]);
    }
  }
}


int main()
{
  std::vector<char> x = {'H','e','l','l','W','o','l','d'};
  std::vector<char> values = {'r','o'};
  std::vector<size_t> positions = {6,4};
  
  print(x);
  insertAtPositions(x,values,positions);
  print(x);
  
}
```

It prints, as expected

```
H e l l W o l d 
H e l l o W o r l d
```

**Are there faster (or better in some other respect) implementations?**

Note that

1. in practice, `x`'s size typically ranges from 0 to 10^7 and `positions` (and `values`)'s size typically ranges from 0 to 50.
2. I have good reasons for using a vector and not a deque despite this insertion.

Comment: A single tiny hint: for `.size() == 0`, I'd write `.empty()` due to better readability of the intentions IMO.

Comment: Definitional problem:  You can get a different result by first sorting the indexes!

Answer (score 1):

- We need to include `<algorithm>` for `std::sort` and `<cassert>` for `assert`.
- `void print(std::vector<T> &x)`: Since we don't modify the vector, this should take a `const&` (and use a `const&` internally in the range-based for loop).
- `void reorder(std::vector<T> &v, std::vector<uint32_t> &order)`: Again, `order` can be a `const&`.
- We should use `std::size_t` for indices into a vector, not `uint32_t` or `size_t`.
- If we need a signed type for dealing with index differences, we should use `std::ptrdiff_t`, not `int`. It might be easier to count forwards, and then calculate the indices we need inside the loop though.
- There's no point in `std::move`ing a `char`.

---

Rather than inserting elements in-place, we can create a new vector and copy the elements over, selecting from the appropriate source at each index. This doesn't require any more memory than calling `x.resize()`.

e.g.:

```
{
    std::vector<char> x = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'W', 'o', 'l', 'd'};
    std::vector<char> values = {'r', 'o'};
    std::vector<size_t> positions = {6, 4};

    auto indices = sort_indices(positions);
    reorder(positions, indices);
    reorder(values, indices);

    auto size = x.size() + values.size();

    auto y = std::vector<char>();
    y.reserve(size);

    auto v = std::size_t{ 0 }; // index into x
    auto p = std::size_t{ 0 }; // index into positions / values

    for (auto i = std::size_t{ 0 }; i != size; ) // index into y
    {
        if (v == positions[p])
        {
            y.push_back(values[p]);
            ++p;
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            y.push_back(x[v]);
            ++v;
            ++i;
        }
    }

    print(y);
}
```

Since we expect the `x` vector to be much larger than the `values` to be inserted, we could copy larger ranges from `x` in the `else` branch above, something like:

```
            auto beg = v;
            auto end = (p == positions.size() ? x.size() : positions[p]);

            y.insert(y.end(), x.begin() + beg, x.begin() + end);
            v = end;
            i += (beg - end);
```

(Warning: code not properly tested).

Comment: "This doesn't require any more memory than calling `x.resize()`." That's not generally true. Especially with the given typical sizes those few additional entries may very often not lead to a reallocation. (Of course given that no `shrink_to_fit` was called before or the last reallocation was due to a call to `resize`.) And about `std::move`ing a `char`: The function is implemented as a template.